# How can I make iTunes start again after disabling it?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

Since iTunes tries to steal my 'Play' button on my keyboard, I disabled it a few months ago. I now wish to buy a movie from the iTunes Store, which means I have to re-enable iTunes.

Problem is: I can't remember what I did to disable it. Currently, after disabling it, starting iTunes shows the icon bouncing but then doesn't launch any windows. Reinstalling iTunes doesn't help. On the command line, I get the following output:

```
open /Applications/iTunes.app 
2015-03-14 21:03:43.082 open[67755:13439350] Metadata.framework [Error]: void _MDItemMarkAsUsedForPath(CFStringRef): was called with a NULL path
```

**How can I make iTunes start again?**

Comment: Perhaps you have used https://github.com/thebitguru/play-button-itunes-patch/ ? It seems to remove a path, and since this can't find a path, that may be it.

Answer (score 1):

Figured this one out myself:

- Re-disabled iTunes via [Play Button ITunes Patch](http://www.thebitguru.com/projects/iTunesPatch?utm_source=guiapp&utm_medium=guiapp&utm_campaign=about-window)
- This (while still stopping iTunes from eating the play button) now makes iTunes launch normally again.